# Modeling bending walls

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror-modifier, curve-modifier

I'm working on an environment piece and im stuck on how to model it. Ive included the reference photo what has red and black lines on it. I plan to mirror the wall piece which is indicated by the red circle but Im stuck on how to make all the black pieces the same size.

I need the doorways to be evenly sized as well as the wall insets to be evenly sized. Does anyone have any modeling advice for how to achieve this? Im mostly stuck becauase of the curvature of the wall.

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried with a Curve modifier?

Comment: @moonboots yes I've tried the curvature modifier but it heavily distorts the location of my wall, here's a link to what it looks like with the curvature cause I don't know how to upload screenshots. Also, for the curve I used the line from the base floor and converted it to a curve https://we.tl/t-ugdt7oUKNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your plane, go in *Edit* mode, rotate 90° on Z, subdivide your plane, set its origin to its geometry, put it at the same location as the curve:

[image]

Array it on X, choose X as *Deform Axis* in the *Curve* modifier:

[image]